# If while statements within if loop on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, while-loop

I have written some basic PHP to get the Permalink and title of any post within a certain category. This was written for the footer and works just fine.

My issue is now when I try to use the same code within an if loop, it fails.

What should I be doing differently?

Here is my code:

```
<?php if (in_category('training'))
{

<?php query_posts('category_name=training'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

}

elseif (in_category('club'))

{

<?php query_posts('category_name=club'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

}

else

{

echo "Nothing to show";

}

 ?>
```

Comment: can you tell what error you are getting.

Comment: There is no error unfortunately. The content just below the loop just doesn't load.

Comment: Have you tried with wp_debug true in your settings to see if any error shows up? Or if you get any error in webservers error log?

Comment: I hadn't. Sorry, this is all still fairly new to me.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/thames_new/wp-content/themes/expound/side-bar.php on line 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please use this

<?php if (in_category('training'))
{

 query_posts('category_name=training'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; endif; 

}

elseif (in_category('club'))

{
query_posts('category_name=club'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; endif; 
}

else

{

echo "Nothing to show";

}

 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks :-) This has solved the original issue, although now every post within that category is show on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use one or more query in same page.USe <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> after loop.